# Pattern Formation book

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I want to initiate me into the study of pattern formation. I am motived by the work of Alan Turing (1952). What book do you recommend to star?

PD : I'm studied mathematics and computation.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this book: http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/gold/pdfs/teaching/cross_hohenberg.pdf . I haven't used it by myself yet, but it seems to be an interesting addition to your searches.